# cannot load such file -- Config/Data/data_form.yml (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

In this class I am loading the yaml file

```
require "./TestData"
require 'yaml'
class CardSubmission < Application
  include PageObject
  include DataMagic
  include TestData

  def initialize(browser)
    @browser = browser
  end

  def submit_application(data = {})
    DataMagic.load ("data_form.yml")
    populate_page_with data_for(:Auto_Data, data)
  end
end
```

Comment: try `./data_form.yml`

Comment: Thanks Albin, I have tryed the above one but I am getting same error.

Answer (score 2):

Data Magic assumes that the YAML files are in a "config/data" folder. If that is not the case, you need to specify the directory to look in:

```
DataMagic.yml_directory = 'data/yml'
```

If the file is in the current directory, the directory would be:

```
DataMagic.yml_directory = '.'
```

This would be called at the start of your script (or at least before calling `DataMagic.load`).

As an example,

```
DataMagic.yml_directory = 'pages/config/data'
DataMagic.load('data_form.yml')
```

Will expect the file 'pages/config/data/data_form.yml' to exist with respect to the working directory. It is not relative to the file that calls `DataMagic.yml_directory=` (ie env.rb). Assuming you have the typical folder structure of:

- project

  - features

    - step_definitions
    - support

      - env.rb

You would be calling `cucumber` from the "project" directory, which makes it your working directory. The `yml_directory` is relative to this directory. Therefore our example expects the folder structure:

- project

  - pages

    - config

      - data

        - data_form.yml
  - features

    - step_definitions
    - support

      - env.rb

Comment: Thanks Justin, But I am getting same error. I am calling DataMagic.yml_directory = 'Config/data/data_form.yml' in env.rb

Comment: You are not setting the `DataMagic.yml_directory` correctly. This is meant to only be the _directory_ that contains your YAML files. It should not be both the directory and file. In other words, `DataMagic.yml_directory` specifies where to look and `DataMagic.load` specifies which file within that directory.

Comment: If the example does not clarify how to solve your problem, you likely need to give more information. Specifically,  what is your folder structure, where are you running the test from and where is the YAML located.

Comment: Scenario: Verify the xxx
  Given I am on xxx web page
  When I provide application information
  And I select xxx button
  And I click on xxx
  Then I should xxx
Here is when:

When(/^I provide application information$/) do
  submission = CardSubmission.new(@browser)
  submission.submit_application
end

Here the TestData module:

module TestData
  include PageObject
text_field(:name, :id => 'Name')
text_field(:mail, :id => 'Mail')
end
I am calling the data_magic gem in env:

DataMagic.yml_directory = 'pages/Config/data/data_form.yml'

Comment: My project structure is:     project
                                                Pages
                                                    config
                                                         data      data_form.yml

Comment: I have updated the example to match your file location. Please take a look again at how to set the `DataMagic.yml_directory`. Notice that it **should not** include `data_form.yml` (ie the file).

Comment: Now I am getting this error    Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - config\data/default.yml

Comment: Without knowing what you changed/did, there isn't much more I can help you with. Have you tried using DataMagic by itself (ie without using Cucumber or a large project)? If you do something more simple, maybe you'll then be able to apply that knowledge to the more complex situation.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Justin Ko